# Styling of button in mono for android

Tags: c#, android, button, xamarin.android

I'm absolute beginner when it comes to *mono for android*.

Referring to below screenshot, the default button style *(left image)* doesn't look good here. So I want to change it to exact rectangle *(right image)* and not rounded-rectangle(the default one).

Any idea on this?

Any xml file need to be added?

***As I'm very new to this, any help will be appreciated !!***

[image: screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code for creating rounded corners button background

res/drawable/rounded_bg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--  res/drawable/rounded_bg.xml -->
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
   <solid android:color="@color/blue1"/>
   <corners
       android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
       android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
   android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
   android:topRightRadius="5dp"/>  
</shape>
```

and use that as background for your button

```
android:background="@drawable/rounded_bg"
```

Comment: Thnx a lot for your response. But I've created button programmatically. So instead of `android:background="@drawable/rounded_bg"`, what should be used?

Comment: button.setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.rounded_bg);

Comment: I knew this stmt. But I'm using `mono for android`, so this doesn't work here as it treats `R.drawable.rounded_bg` as integer and hence the error `can't convert from int to drawable`.

Comment: try this setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.nohighlight);

Comment: Try `button.SetBackgroundDrawable(Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.rounded_bg))`

Comment: Although I think button.SetBackgroundDrawable(Resource.Drawable.rounded_bg) should also work - if it doesn't then post more info.

Comment: when I used this `btn.SetBackgroundDrawable(Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.rounded_bg‌​));`, I'm getting whole black screen, but elements are clickable but not visible.

Comment: **rounded_bg.xml  : ** `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
   <corners
       android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
       android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
   android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
   android:topRightRadius="5dp"/>  
</shape>`